# Trying to get content from span using simple html dom parser in PHP

Tags: php, html

**I am trying to get content from this span**

```
<span class="contact-seller-name ng-binding">martin</span>
```

Here's my code

```
require 'simple_html_dom.php';

$url = "https://www.donedeal.ie/cars-for-sale/bmw-520d-m-sport-f10/14712042?campaign=3";

$html = file_get_html($url);

$value = $html->find("span[class*=contact-seller-name ng-binding]", 0);

echo $value->innertext;
```

But the problem is I've always getting this error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
> E:\Programs\xampp\htdocs\personal\php dom\WebScraping\test3.php on line 30

Comment: Which one is line 30 though?

Comment: echo $value->innertext;

Comment: try  find("span[class=contact-seller-name]"

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov still getting the same error

Comment: please check print_r($html) - is it NULL or not?

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov html in not null I've checked it

Comment: I can't see any `span` in writted url.

Comment: @Mohammad have you checked in https://www.donedeal.ie/cars-for-sale/bmw-520d-m-sport-f10/14712042?campaign=3

Comment: Yes, there isn't any span in it.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$value` as an array:

```
<?php 
    // finding against the multiple
    // 0 is for the first span element
    $value = $html->find('span#ur_span_id');
    foreach($value  as $p) {
        $span_test =  $p->outertext; 
    }
    //can use class too in find section
?>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. As fas as I see, you are using a completely different selector

Comment: For example // Find all element which id=foo
$ret = $html->find('#foo');

// Find all element which class=foo
$ret = $html->find('.foo');

// Find all element has attribute id
$ret = $html->find('*[id]');

// Find all anchors and images
$ret = $html->find('a, img');

// Find all anchors and images with the "title" attribute
$ret = $html->find('a[title], img[title]');     For additional details kindly review https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm

Comment: Please add all explanation **to your answer**